# Customer Master - Contact Person details

Tags: abap, sap-erp

I'm new in SAP dev. I have to get details (name, tel) of Contact Person in base of Customer Master (KNA1-KUNNR). [ Contact Person at Delivery Address ]. Can someone tell me what fields and in which table store this info?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve the problem? Maybe you have some code to begin with. Otherwise the question seems to broad.

Comment: For addresses use adrc table, name for customers lay in the same table in fields name1/name2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any time you need to get data from standard SAP objects check if they provided a BAPI for it, especially if the data is stored over multiple linked database tables. 
It seems that for your purpose you have BAPI_CUSTOMER_GETCONTACTLIST.